# Secunet SINA cannot esablish secure connection

Tags: networking

Secunet [SINA](https://www.bsi.bund.de/EN/Themen/Oeffentliche-Verwaltung/Zulassung/SINA/sina.html) allows to access the company network remotely from an appropiately configured laptop. This works nicely, e.g from a friend's private home networks, but not when they bring it to our private home network: SINA can see the network, but dispays the red sign and says "cannot establish secure connection" ("kann keine sichere Internetbeziehung etablieren"), even though SINA seems to connect successfull to the internet as such (it offers to disconnect). Same with WiFi and LAN cable.

**Update:** The new device (SINA) hat captured a restricted access profile which blocked "everything except surfing and mail (i.e. TCP/UDP)", resolved by an unrestricted profile. **SINA obviously requires a special port or protocol beyond TCP/UDP - which?** (hitherto unknown to me due to lack of public documentation, at least not found by me on their website or by Google). I.e. it works now, but I'd like to narrow devices' rights to the minimum.

Comment: Are you using it as software installed on a laptop, or as a dedicated gateway device? If it's installed software, is there anything you can see in a packet capture program? Have you tried asking the people who have issued you with the connection? As this seems to be the kind of product to deliberately have little to no public documentation available (except that it apparently uses IPsec), I don't think any of us could really answer.

Comment: Update from trobleshooting (see also edited question):  The new device (SINA) hat captured a restricted Fritzbox access profile which Update: blocked "everything except surfing and mail", resolved by an unrestricted profile. SINA obviously requires a special protocol/ports - hitherto unknown to me due to lack of public documentation, at least not found by me on their website or by Google. I.e. it works now, but I'd like to narrow devices' rights to the minimum. Happy in case someone e.g. from BfI can help, we will ask also directly.

Comment: @user1686: Thanks, I completely agree - not so common. Installed on laptop. Would have to dig deeper in packet capture approaches. They did ask the company IT people - but may not always be the fastest department.

Comment: If it's installed on a computer, can you also install Wireshark on the same computer and take a look yourself?